# numpy bitwise operation error

Tags: python, numpy

numpy version 1.9.0

```
1 & (2**63)
0

np.bitwise_and(1, 2**63)
TypeError: ufunc 'bitwise_and' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''

np.bitwise_and(1, 2**63 + 100)
TypeError: ufunc 'bitwise_and' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''

np.bitwise_and(1, 2**64)
0
```

Is this a bug or am I missing something?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

convert to `uint64` first:

```
np.bitwise_and(np.uint64(1), np.uint64(2**63))
```

Here is the code to check the rule to convert python integer to numpy integer:

```
print np.array([2**30]).dtype
print np.array([2**31]).dtype
print np.array([2**63]).dtype
print np.array([2**64]).dtype
```

output:

```
int32
int64
uint64
object
```

I think `np.bitwise_and(1, 2**63)` raise error because `2**63` is out of the range of int32 and int64.

`np.bitwise_and(1, 2**64)` works because it will use Python's long object.

We need to read the source code to understand the detail.

Comment: It works. Do you think this is a bug or is there a reason that a manual convert is needed here? Note that 2**64 doesn't have any problem.